# window phone 8 emulator internet connection

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, connection, windows-phone-8

I was using the win8 phone emulator, but it's internet explorer could not display webpage ,showing no connectivity to internet. I checked a lot from microsoft site and tried, I'm sure that i enabled automatic DNS server. 
I'm using wifi connection.

I saw lot of people having this issues as well, have anyone success to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I configured the Windows Phone Emulator External Interface, on my emulator image. Here is what i did:

- Open you Hyper-V Manager
- Right click on the emulator image settings
- Click on Windows Phone Emulator External Interface
- Bind the Virtual switch to your physical network device (on my mbpro was the Intel Pro)

Comment: hmm, sorry, how to bind? is that enable virtual lan identification?? beside, im having 2 window phone emulator external

Comment: can anyone explain how to bind Virtual switch to your physical network device

Comment: What do you mean by "bind" ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case only **Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch** was configured.
Therefore, I had to add the external switch using those steps:

1. Open the **Hyper-V Manager**, and click on your computer name in the
   left pane (under Hyper-V Manager).
2. Under **Actions** (on the right), click **Virtual Switch Manager..**
   Virtual Switch Manager window will open, displaying all the
   configured virtual switches.
3. Verify that you have only one switch - named **Windows Phone
   Emulator Internal Switch**. Its Connection type configured as
   **Internal network**. Leave it as is.
4. Now add a new (external) virtual network switch:
   Set the Connection type to **External Network**, choose your active network adapter and check the **Allow management operating system to share this network adapter**.
5. Save the changes and restart your emulator.

You can find more details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/10/01/why-can-t-the-windows-phone-emulator-go-online.aspx).